# Add dropped column after imputer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

For the imputer to work, I have dropped “City” column and created a new data frame named “data_numberOnly”.  After the fit and transform, I need to append the City column. How to add this column?

Code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

columns = ['Population','PerCapita_Income','City']
p = np.array([[1,2.0, 'Atlanta'],[4,np.nan, 'Phoenix'],(1,3.,'Raleigh')])

#Create data frame from array
df3 = pd.DataFrame(p)
df3.columns = columns

#drop non-numeric columns for imputer to work
data_numberOnly = df3.drop('City', axis=1)

imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
imp.fit(data_numberOnly)     
X = imp.transform(data_numberOnly)
X
```

Source Data Frame

[image]

After Transform

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace it back to `df3` by selecting the target columns.

```
df3[['Population','PerCapita_Income']] = X

df3
    Population PerCapita_Income City
0   1   2   Atlanta
1   4   2.5 Phoenix
2   1   3   Raleigh
```

or Create the new one

```
df = pd.DataFrame(X)
df['City'] = df3['City'].copy()
df.columns = columns
df

Population  PerCapita_Income    City
0   1.0 2.0 Atlanta
1   4.0 2.5 Phoenix
2   1.0 3.0 Raleigh
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the column using `np.hstack`

```
X = np.hstack([X,df3['City'][:,None]])
```

you need the `[:,None]` part to transform the pd.Series from 1D to a 2D array with 1 column (there are similar tricks that also work)

```
X
array([[1.0, 2.0, 'Atlanta'],
       [4.0, 2.5, 'Phoenix'],
       [1.0, 3.0, 'Raleigh']], dtype=object)
```